# java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: jdk.internal.reflect.GeneratedSerializationConstructorAccessor1

Tags: java, android, kotlin, gradle, lang

what's reason of it ? I have migrated to gradle 7.02 and agp 7.0.2

[image]

Comment: Have u tried clean and rebuild?

Comment: yes , clean , rebuild , invalidate cache and restart , deleting cache all done .. but no chance